# Handling SystemExceptions in mule esb

Tags: mule

I have an global JMS activemq-connector with reconnection strategy defined.
When activemq-server goes down, after retries exhausted i see a error log below.

```
ERROR DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy:337 - Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

how to handle DefaultSystemException and perform a set of activities like sending exception message to vm endpoint.

Does anyone across this situation please help.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: I understand that there is a need of writing a custom exceptions as mentioned [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Error+Handling#ErrorHandling-SystemExceptions). Can any one provide any sample for the same.

Comment: my question is somthing similar to [this](http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Overriding-SystemExceptionHandler-in-Mule-3-0-0-td3271349.html#a3271494)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Default Exception Strategy with the a Custom Global Default Exception Strategy.  This way the JMS connection failure exception might be caught

More on this at the below link.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Error+Handling#ErrorHandling-CustomDefaultExceptionStrategies

Hope this helps.